# Парсинг csrf-токена для дальнейшей авторизации

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, csrf

выводит такую ошибку после запуска кода, в чём заключается проблема?

Ошибка:

```
csrf = auth_bs.select('input[name=crsf_token]')[0]['value']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

s = requests.Session()

auth_html = s.get('https://www.betonsuccess.ru/')
auth_bs = BS(auth_html.content, 'html.parser')
csrf = auth_bs.select('input[name=crsf_token]')[0]['value']

print(csrf)
```

Comment: Похоже, тут вернулся пустой список `auth_bs.select('input[name=crsf_token]')`

Comment: для нахождения одного элемента используйте select_one

Comment: а так, выведите soup и проверьте наличие token